# i am looking for the objective function for GAFCM

Tags: python, firebase-cloud-messaging, genetic-algorithm

i am looking for python code of the objective function that evaluates fuzzy c means genetic algorithm (GAFCM) using centers as population

```
def distfcm_(data, V):
    dist = np.zeros((V.shape[0], data.shape[0]))
    for k in range(V.shape[0]):
        dist[k, :] = np.sqrt(np.sum((data - np.ones((150, 4)) * V[k, :])**2, axis=1))
    return dist

def fitness_function(X,C ,c, m, alfa):
    dist = distfcm_(X, C)
    cluster_n = 3
    expo = 2
    tmp = dist ** (2 / -(expo - 1))
    U = tmp / (np.ones(tmp.shape) * np.sum(tmp, axis=0))
    mf = U ** expo
    obj_fcn = np.sum(np.sum((dist ** 2) * mf))
    return obj_fcn
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am trying to optimize the fuzzy c means algorithm with genetic algorithm by using centers as paramater, what i need is the objective function to calculate the fitness of each pop in population of centers